# What does it mean by java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 0

Tags: java, arrays

my compiler keep pointing at this line:

```
arr[i] = new specialDelivery(name,name2,weight,special);
```

and this :

```
arr[i] = new specialDelivery(name,name2,weight,special);
```

the error is stated in the title

```
public static void main ( String args [] )
{   
    int size = 0,distance;
    double weight = 0.0;
    String strinput,method,name,name2,special;
    Parcel arr[] = new Parcel[size];

    strinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( " Enter number of parcel : " );
    size = Integer.parseInt(strinput);

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {   
        int j = 0, k = 0;

        method = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Method of delivery (normal/special):  " );  

        if (method.equals("normal"))
        {
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( " Enter your name : " );
            name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( " Enter name of receiver : " );
            strinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the weight of parcel " + j + " : " );  
            weight = Double.parseDouble(strinput);

            strinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the distance of delivery " + j + " (km) : " );  
            distance = Integer.parseInt(strinput);

            j++;
            arr[i] = new normalDelivery(name,name2,weight,distance); 
        }     

        if (method.equals("special"))
        {
           name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( " Enter your name : " );
           name2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( " Enter name of receiver : " ); 
           special = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the type of delivery(airplane/ship) :" );
           strinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter the weight of parcel " + j + " : " ); 
           weight = Double.parseDouble(strinput);

           j++;
           arr[i] = new specialDelivery(name,name2,weight,special);
        }
    }
}    
}
```

Comment: `int size = 0,distance;` what is this?

Comment: It means the array has 0 size. That's the only size of array without one element (accessible as the 0th index). Then it's just a matter of finding out why the size is 0 .. work backwards.

Comment: @user2246674: No, an array with *zero* elements does *not* have any elements. Therefore, you can not index *any* element in array without obtaining and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, including the zeroth index.

Comment: When you see `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : n`, and the array that was indexed into, the JVM runtime is telling you that `n` is not a valid index for the array; in particular it means that `n < 0 or n > array.length - 1`. In your case, the JVM is reporting an `n` of `0`. This means that `0` is not a valid index for your array. This means that the array does not have *any* elements. Now, how did that happen? Let's trace back to when the array was declared: `Parcel arr[] = new Parcel[size];` Okay, what about `size`? `int size = 0`. There it is. You need to calculate `size` before.

Comment: @Kon, it's valid syntax. You can declare multiple variables of the same type like that, and in this case, `distance` has a default value of `0`, while `size` has an explicitly declared value of `0`. I'm not sure why he only explicitly declared one of them, but there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 9):

You have declared an array of size `0`, because that's what `size` was when the array was created.  So you can't assign anything to this array.  On top of that, the array's size is fixed at 0, so you can't do anything to change the size of it.

Create your array after you have assigned a number to `size`, so it has the proper size from the start:

```
strinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( " Enter number of parcel : " );
size = Integer.parseInt(strinput);

Parcel arr[] = new Parcel[size];  // move this line down here
```

Comment: thanks a lot that helped. I was finding the solution for hours but I never thought the solution would be this simple

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
int size = 0;
...
Parcel arr[] = new Parcel[size];
```

Therefore, you've created an array with length 0. Since arr[0] attempts to access the first element, but a zero-length array has zero elements, you get that exception. You will have to either allocate the array with an appropriate non-zero size, or use a dynamic container such as an `ArrayList`.